# Multiple URL from Custom post name

Tags: php, permalinks, url-rewriting

I would like to do something special for a website in Wordpress. I have a "custom post type" whose data are all "post custom fields" except the name of the post. I need to create multiple urls for each of the "post custom fields" of the same post, and shows custom post field value.

For example

The custom post type is custompostA 
This custom post type has the following "custom post fields": customfieldA, customfieldB

I add a new post whose title is "Example1"

Based on this, I want two different urls

www.domain.com/custompostA/Example1/customfieldA 
www.domain.com/custompostA/Example1/customfieldB

The first URL will display the customfieldA value and the second URL will display customfieldB value

I hope I have been clear since my exposure.

Thank you very much
Javier

Comment: are there just the two fields, or might they vary and be numerous?

Comment: No, there are multiple fields (about 20 or 25).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a query var and a rewrite rule to handle the extra URL data-

Add the `wpd_cf` query var to the list of known query vars:

```
function wpd_add_query_var( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'wpd_cf';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_add_query_var' );
```

Add a rewrite rule to handle the incoming requests and set the `wpd_cf` query var. This particular rule will match upper and lower case alphabet plus a hyphen. WordPress has a default rule in place to capture numbers after the post name for multi-page posts, so this will avoid capturing those requests. The first argument should match the URL slug of your custom post type, the second argument should set the key you registered your custom post type under.

```
function wpd_add_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'custompostA/([^/]+)/([-A-Za-z]+)/?$',
        'index.php?custompostA=$matches[1]&wpd_cf=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_rewrite_rule' );
```

Then in the template (or a template filter) you can check the value of `wpd_cf`:

```
$the_requested_field = get_query_var( 'wpd_cf' );
```

Don't forget to flush rewrite rules after making any changes, this can be done by visiting the Permalinks Settings page in admin.

Comment: Thanks Milo. My custom post type it's "creacion-empresas". My post name it's "espana" and my custom field name it's "forma_juridica". When i put "domain.com/creacion-empresas/espana/forma_juridica" I recive 404 page

Comment: you have to add the underscore to the regex pattern if you want to match that: `[_-A-Za-z]`

Comment: Nice it works. But i have a problem. Link canononial it's the same for all custom fields. What can i do? If i leave this, google only indexes one post ant not indexes custom fields

Comment: You'll have to [remove](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) the `rel_canonical` action from `wp_head` and add your own function to output it. Look in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` to see where the original is added, and `wp-includes/link-template.php` to see the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you COULD do this by using the Pods plugin.  it would require a recode of what you are doing but Pods native support of wildcard support would make this possible and wouldn't take too much code to implement.

Comment: I cannot install Pods Plugin. This plugin makes an SQL error on my website

Comment: What's the error?